# library and application package name conflict issue - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, package, vpn, strongswan

Trying to import open source StrongswanVPN project as library in my project (StrongSwanVPN is also an application on playstore), my application working fine with this library, but I can only install one application, either my application or strongswanVPN(from playstore), there is package conflict issue, I am unable to install both applications at same time. please help me out

Comment: You have to change your package name as you can't use two application with same package name at same time

Comment: Your package name must be a unique identifier. So its better to update the package name, otherwise you might face issues when trying to upload your app on playstore too.

Comment: its already published on playstore can't change it now, and problem is not with my app package name, problem is with library package name,

Comment: So are you saying both your application and strongswan vpn application has same package name and both are available on playstore?

Comment: my app package name is different but the package name of library module I am using in my app, is same with the app already available on playstore